# Cant use eventlisteners with chrome extention

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to make a chrome extention but my event listeners wont fire.. Here is my code:

```
document.querySelector(".bird").ondblclick = () => init();

const init = () => {
  //hide unnessecary elements
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  document.querySelector("#footer").style.opacity = 0;
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

  //Now we create the game UI
  let UI = document.createElement("DIV");
  UI.id = "Game-UI";

  //after we created the game UI we will append all elements to the UI
  let startText = document.createElement("SPAN");
  startText.innerHTML = "Press space to start...";
  startText.className = "startText";
  UI.append(startText);

  document.body.append(UI);

  //if the UI is loaded then we start doing things this is to prevent the script from executing to fast
  startText.addEventListener("load", flicker);
}

const flicker = () => { //this needs to fire
  console.log("this");
  (() => { //in here we do the flicker animation for the starttext
    let on = true;
    setInterval(function() {
      on != on;
      if (on) {
        console.log("reached!");
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

I searched arround the web but I could not find any solution to this problem. I also noticed that I could not find any reference to the injected file in the event inspector in chrome.

Additional here is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Ontdek Het Wad easteregg",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Super dom dit",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.ontdekhetwad.nl/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["/js/src/game.js", "/js/includes/matter.min.js"],
      "css": ["/css/gameUI.css"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Without a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve) it's not clear where you run/inject this code. Typical mistakes are 1) loading the script before html has been parsed - solved by moving the script tag before `</body>`, 2) not using the popup's devtools which is invoked by right-clicking the popup, 3) running a content script before the page has initialized via its dynamic script - solved by using event delegation on something that's guaranteed to exist like document.body or waiting for the element to appear via setTimeout/MutationObserver etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm I ruled these all out in my research before this question. The manifest is atm just a standard manifest with content_script

Comment: If you don't see your content script in devtools it means either it's not properly declared (show your manifest.json), or the extension wasn't reloaded on chrome://extensions page, or the web page wasn't reloaded after reloading/updating the extension (the content script is not executed automatically in this case), or you're looking in the wrong place https://puu.sh/BAagc/9fb109f1f5.png

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeah I found the content scripts but the thing is that I cant find the events I create in devtools all the DOM events I create just wont work the only one that works is the window events

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in your content script, reload the page, and debug the script as it runs.

Comment: @wOxxOm that doesnt get me further..

Comment: Yep, this is as far as I can guess too. Consider providing a proper MCVE.